# c++ process scheduling questions

Tags: c++, iterator

I am working on code which implements a Multilevel Feedback Queue Scheduler.  There is something not clear in a part of the code:

```
void Scheduler_MFQS :: fill_queue(int clk) {
    list<Process>::iterator itr;
    for(itr = processes.begin(); itr != processes.end(); itr++) {
            if((itr -> has_arrived(clk)) && (!queues[0].contains(*itr))) {
                    Process tmp (*itr);
                    queues[0].add_process(tmp); 
                    remove(processes.begin(), processes.end(), *itr);
             }
    }       
}
```

What this basically does is just put the process into the base queues under some condition. But i don't know what `Process tmp (*itr);` means?  However, it compiles legally.  Does that mean create a Process object called tmp?  But what is the next, iterator `(*itr)` mean in c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Process tmp (*itr);" mean?
```

It calls Process(const Process& &) copy constructor to create tmp object;

```
what is the next, iterator (*itr) mean in c++?
```

itr is std::list::iterator type, it's a pointer to current list node. *itr is getting the content of itr, which is a Process.

Your code can enhance a bit, demo as below:

```
   // list<Process>::iterator itr; // move this into for loop, narrow variable scope and lifetime
    /*auto if C++11*/
     processes.unique();  // you actually only want unique processes from list
    for(list<Process>::iterator itr = processes.begin(); itr != processes.end(); ++itr) 
                                                         ^^ call preincrement, faster
    {
        if((itr -> has_arrived(clk)) /*&& (!queues[0].contains(*itr))*/) {
                                     ^^ process list contains unique item only, no need to compare
         //Process tmp (*itr); comment out this line, save one object copy
         queues[0].add_process(*itr);              
         //remove(processes.begin(), processes.end(), *itr);   
         // You don't need to clear item in the loop              
        }
    }

   processes.clear();   // or swap with an empty list
   // std::list<Process> p2;
   // p2.swap(ps);
```

Answer (score 1):

**itr** is the iterator which points to some container element(list in your case). When you use asterisk(*) on iterator you gain access to its content i.e. to the actual element of the list. In your case it is a Process object.

Comment: yes, i know *itr means a Process element in list<Process>, but what is the "Process tmp(*itr);" mean  in c++? never met that kind format before...

Comment: It is construction of Process object(tmp) by copy-constructor.